# retrieving sharepoint online authentication cookie and using it elsewhere

Tags: authentication

so if a person goes to sharepoint online, logs in, how can I get the cookie that tells sharepoint later on that you are logged in so I can have something else use it and access sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly understanding, you are asking how to programmatically get SharePoint auth cookies?

In .net you can use [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) to get cookies see example below:

```
var login    = "admin@***.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "P@ssw0rd";
var siteUrl  = "https://***.sharepoint.com/";

var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, password);
var auth  = creds.AuthenticateAsync(new Uri(siteUrl), true);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteUrl);
request.CookieContainer = auth.Result.CookieContainer;

var result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: can you do the same sort of thing is you ended up with a SAML token as well? Does that work the same way or no?  I may have the option to get a SAML token from else where but not sure what to do with it afterwards.

Comment: and what you authenticated through your sharepoint URL first?

Comment: I don't see what you mean, could you explain in more detail?